# New browser window every new iteration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python, unit-tests

I need to open every new iteration, new browser windows. For example:

```
class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.browser = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()
        cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.browser, 20)
        cls.browser.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_01_goole(self):
        for i in range(3):
            browser = self.browser
            browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

In this situation I don't see new browser windows. But in this situation:

```
class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    # @classmethod
    # def setUpClass(cls):
        # cls.browser = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()
        # cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.browser, 20)
        # cls.browser.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_01_goole(self):
        for i in range(3):
            # browser = self.browser
            browser = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()
            browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

I receive 3 new browser windows (browser_incognito.chrome_incognito() it's another module that I created). I need browser from setUpClass().

Comment: Why do you want to loop in the test? Wouldn't it be better to create three separate tests?

Comment: In my situation I need create users (for example I need 8 users), every iteration I create new user, the problem is that all user must to do google authorization, and where is the problem, the problem is when I start new iteration after I created new user in previously iteration the browser record session for previously user and I can't continue with my process. So for solution of this problem I want to use  chrome incognito, and every iteration open new chrome incognito windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setUpClass()` this is only run once when the testClass is created.

I think you want to use **`setUp()`** instead which is called before each test.

> setUp(): Method called to prepare the test fixture. This is called
>   immediately before calling the test method; other than AssertionError
>   or SkipTest, any exception raised by this method will be considered an
>   error rather than a test failure. The default implementation does
>   nothing.

Read the documentation to understand the difference better: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-cases

For having setting up multiple browsers in your setup functions you could try to create an array.

```
def setUp(cls):
    cls.browser[1] = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()
    cls.browser[2] = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()
    cls.browser[3] = browser_incognito.chrome_incognito()

def test(self):
    for i in range(3):
        browser = self.browser[i]
        browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: It's still open only one window.

Comment: Ah sorry miss read your question, you want ONE test to have three browsers windows open, not each test having a fresh browser.

Comment: Yes, in one test I want open every iteration, new browsers windows.